# Flexbox - make footer stick to the bottom of the page at all times?

Tags: css, flexbox

I know, this has been asked 1000 times but NO solution from stackoverflow seem to work for me.

Everyone does stuff like `.container { height: 100vh; }` while the whole idea is to have footer at the bottom if main content of the page has not enough content to stretch.

Parent has `flex` as display and `column` direction. Children have `flex-grow: 1` and `flex-shrink: 0` respectively. Why does it not work? Why is footer not at the very bottom? What am I missing? I don't know height or footer or main, I want the main to take up all the free space at all times.

JSFiddle version: https://jsfiddle.net/6v2gb1s0/

```css
* {
  border: solid 1px red;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {   
  flex-grow: 1; 
}

footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;    
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <main>main content</main>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `footer` won't go to the bottom because the `height` of the `#container` is not set.

If you set

```css
#container {
  height: 100%
}
```

The `footer` will go to the bottom (albeit there will have a scroll because of the margins, so you gotta compensate for that).

Check it out:
[image: Edit blissful-babycat-0rivmi]

Comment: 100% might not work because the body doesn't always extend to the end of its content. I would use `100vh` instead: https://codepen.io/Kathara/pen/jOYgdJO (might cause other issues though I might not be aware of).

Comment: Agreed, setting the body height to 100% can screw up mobile browsers. Best setting it to min-height:100vh but also beware of margins and box-sizing.

Answer (score 1):

It's fundamentally the way flexbox works. display:flex dictates how its children behave, not the parent element. That element just behaves like a normal div. Thus the parent will try to extend to 100% of the width of the parent container and shrink to the height of the content so you have to set the height (or preferably min-height) to 100%.

To understand more how it works, you can set the body element to display:flex and that will cause its child element (the container) to then stretch like you'd expect, which would be an alterntative to setting the container height to 100%.

Hope this helps.